# Parameters of optimization TCP / IP in Linux Mandriva

Tags: networking, java, mandriva

In the registry of `Windows XP` can find the following options to enable optimizations for `TCP/ IP`:

```
- MSS;
- TCP Rx Window Size;
- SACK (Selective Acknowledgment);
- ECN (Explicit Congestion Notification);
- TCP Window Scaling;
- TCP Timestamping;
- PMTU Discovery;
- TCP Fast Retransmit;
- TCP Fast Recovery;
- Delayed ACK.
```

For example, under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\interfaceGUID` on parameter `IPAddress [REG_MULTI_SZ]` can find the interface and configure a specific network card.

I can manipulate the values ​​of the parameters **programmatically** and see the results.

I am interested in a list of similar parameters in `Linux Mandriva`.
And yet - can I change it from `Java` code?

Comment: Have you simply tried running `man tcp` on your system?  It gives you a list of options for TCP/IP stack and explanations for them.  You can also look at [this website](http://drupal.star.bnl.gov/STAR/blog-entry/jeromel/2009/feb/18/tcp-parameters-linux-kernel)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Karlson!
Thanks for the link.